# how to track chef-solo runtime changes on the client?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I'm inspecting a large cookbook that is about to configure my client and i would like to know exaclly what files it configured \ deleted \ added , and so on.

I run:

```
find / -mount -mmin
```

it did gave me some indication but i also got results that were not relevent.

is there a better way knowing what exaclly was changed on my clinet by running the cookbook?

Answer (score 0):

There is the why-run system which attempts to do an analysis beforehand to work out what would be changed, but it's imperfect due to the nature of Chef recipes as arbitrary executable code. You can also get a listing afterwards via either the Reporting addon or an event handler (which lets you write the data to any system/format you want) but that only reports after the fact.

Comment: using the why-run does not help me becasue in some cases it will only show what block of code will run but not actually what it changed on my system. and regarding the Report add-on or handler, i'm not familiar with it. appreciate if you can share and example .